# дискорд бот для цуефа выдает ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

выдает ошибку expected an indented block
вот в этой строчке

```
async def knb(ctx, choice: str):
**c**hoices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
```

(выделенное жирным отмечает красным)

```
import random
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot (command_prefix='/') # префикс команд для бота

#определяем команду knb (камень-ножницы-бумага)
@bot.command()
async def knb(ctx, choice: str):
choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

#проверяем, что выбор пользователя является допустимым
if choice not in choices:
await ctx.send(f'Выберите: {", ".join(choices)}')
return

bot_choice = random.choice(choices)

#определяем победителя и отправляем результат в чат
if choice == 'rock' and bot_choice == 'scissors' \
or choice == 'paper' and bot_choice == 'rock' \
or choice == 'scissors' and bot_choice == 'paper':
await ctx.send(f'{ ctx.author .mention} победил! Бот выбрал {bot_choice}.')
elif choice == bot_choice:
await ctx.send(f'{ ctx.author .mention}, ничья! Бот выбрал {bot_choice}.')
else:
await ctx.send(f'{ ctx.author .mention} проиграл! Бот выбрал {bot_choice}.')

bot.run ('insert token here') # запуск бота
```

Comment: у вас и дальше будут ошибки, так как вы банально не соблюдаете правила отступов в коде

Comment: перед `choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']` должен быть отступ

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я просто забыл